New line at the help value of an argument
I'm working in Python and I have some arguments that have long description in their help value. How can I do new line so it'll look more aesthetic?
Example:
parser.add_argument('walker_type', help="""

The walker type:

    1 - one-unit random walker

    2 - [0.5-1.5]-unit random walker

    3 - straight-line random walker

    4 - imbalanced random walker**""")

I want that it'll look like the bold rows above when I run it in the command line
I tried using the triple quotes as you can see and it didn't work.
also when I add '\n' to it, it still doesn't show newline.
How can I fix this?

Does this answer your question? How does one output bold text in Bash?

Did you try one of the alternative helpformatter classes, as described in the documentation?

@ti7 The question is about newlines, not about bold text.

indeed - I'd misread that they literally wanted that row to be bold, but the same solution (using another formatter_class) applies to both!

I'd misread your question at first, thinking you wanted to make some line literally bold - you just need to select another formatter_class to your initial ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter .. you may also find textwrap is quite helpful or that you want to inherit from a text formatter to provide a completely custom output
See How to insert newlines on argparse help text? for a variety of options of different complexities and flexibilities
official docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class



formatter_class
use




RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
custom description formatting


RawTextHelpFormatter
custom help text formatting


ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
show named defaults


MetavarTypeHelpFormatter
show type rather than name



Then you can embed newlines
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser("name", "help doc", formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
BOLD_START = "\033[1m"
BOLD_END   = "\033[0m"
p.add_argument("-v", help=f"{BOLD_START}some cool text\nsome more cool text{BOLD_END}")
p.parse_args()



former continuation
I'm somewhat surprised that directly embedding ANSI codes works fine without a custom formatter_class, though it would take extra effort to strip them
If you plan to run your program on Windows, try colorama, which can handle its wacky environment and color codes
relevant shell escape codes

styling How does one output bold text in Bash?
coloring How do I print colored text to the terminal?

Finally, see also blessings, which is generally an improvement over curses
